# How to start a Jetty server without mvn jetty:run (directly from command line)?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, war, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to replicate the behavior of `mvn jetty:run` without actually having to use the maven-jetty-plugin. The plugin packages up all the dependencies nicely into a `{project}.war` file, but obviously this does not include a manifest so I cannot run it directly.

Does anyone know how I can virtually replicate the functionality of the jetty:run feature? That is, start the Jetty webapp instance directly from the command line on a machine where Maven is not installed. If this is impossible (and thus a very incompetent question), please let me know that as well.

Comment: Would unpacking a jetty distribution, copying in the war to the right place, and then run jetty be an option?